# ListView not returning appropriate item selected in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, selectionchanged

I am learning how to design a modern UI interface in WPF using MaterialDesign. I have implemented a SelectionChanged() which triggers when the value of the ListView is clicked. It works for the first time (e.g. Home > Refresh). It also works when I click on a different menu option (e.g. Prof Review > [LM] Create New). However, if I click on the Home > Refresh menu again, it does not display the appropriate message. (I will eventually replace the message by calling in the appropriate UserContents.)
To this extent, I have added separate SelectionChanged() methods to the other menus created, but it still does not work.
Help please.

XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="WPF_StaffReview_v1._0.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_StaffReview_v1._0" 
        xmlns:MaterialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="" Icon="Images/Focus.ico"
        Height="600" Width="1080" 
        MinWidth="500"
        MinHeight="500"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow"
        Foreground="White">
    <!-- Storyboard + Triggers to create a collapsible GridMenu -->
    <!--
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MenuOpen">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="250"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MenuClose">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="250"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="60"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnMenuOpen">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuOpen}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnMenuCollapse">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuClose}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    -->
    
    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <!-- Grid definition -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Header -->
        <Grid Height="60" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF1469BE">
            <!-- Title -->
            <TextBlock Text="Main Dashboard" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="22"/>
            <!-- StackPanel to contain Author + Popup Box-->
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtUser" Text="Logged in " VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18"/>
                <MaterialDesign:PopupBox HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                         Margin="10" 
                                         PlacementMode="BottomAndAlignRightEdges" 
                                         StaysOpen="False">
                    <StackPanel Width="150">
                        <Button x:Name="btnHelp" Content="Help" Click="btnHelp_Click"/>
                        <Separator/>
                        <Button x:Name ="btnLogout" Content="Logout" 
                                Click="btnLogout_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </MaterialDesign:PopupBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Left Navigation Bar Area-->
        <Grid x:Name ="GridMenu" Width="250" Grid.RowSpan="2"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FF1E3C69">
            <!--Logo area -->
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid Height="60" Background="White">
                    <Button x:Name="btnMenuCollapse"
                            Width ="60" Height ="60" 
                            Background="{x:Null}"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Click="btnMenuCollapse_Click">
                        <MaterialDesign:PackIcon Foreground="#FF1E3C69"
                                                 Kind="ArrowLeft"
                                                 Width="25" Height="25"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="btnMenuOpen"
                            Width ="60" Height ="60" 
                            Background="{x:Null}"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Click="btnMenuOpen_Click">
                        <MaterialDesign:PackIcon Foreground="#FF1E3C69"
                                                 Kind="Menu"
                                                 Width="25" Height="25"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel x:Name="Menu" Margin="10"/>
                <Grid>
                    <!-- Navigation menu created here -->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged">
                            <!-- Menu: Home -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <MaterialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Home" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" />
                            <Expander Header="Home" IsExpanded="False" Width="210" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White">
                                    <ListView x:Name="lvMenuHome" Foreground="White" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="lvMenuHome_SelectionChanged">
                                        <ListViewItem Height="60">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="Refresh" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </ListViewItem>
                                    </ListView>
                                </Expander>
                            </StackPanel>
                            
                            <!-- Menu: Prof review -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <MaterialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Pen" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" />
                            <Expander Header="Prof Review" IsExpanded="False" Width="210" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White">
                                <ListView x:Name="lvMenuPReview" Foreground="White" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="lvMenuPReview_SelectionChanged" >
                                    <ListViewItem Height="60">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="[LM] Create New" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        </ListViewItem>
                                        <ListViewItem Height="60">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="[Staff] Set targets" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </ListViewItem>
                                        <ListViewItem Height="60">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="[LM] Agree and finalise" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </ListViewItem>
                                     </ListView>
                            </Expander>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <!-- Menu: Reports -->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <MaterialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Report" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" />
                                <Expander Header="Reports" IsExpanded="False" Width="210" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White">
                                    <ListView Foreground="White" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                                        <ListViewItem Height="60">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="List of Staff by LM" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </ListViewItem>
                                        <ListViewItem Height="60">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="Review by Staff / Dept" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </ListViewItem>
                                    </ListView>
                                </Expander>
                            </StackPanel>



                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>



                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <!-- End Navigation Pane -->


        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelMain" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <!-- // StackPanel cannot be used to display a XAML Window -->
            <ContentControl x:Name="ccMain"  Margin="10">
                <!--<TextBlock Text="Testing" Foreground="Black"/>-->
            </ContentControl>

        </StackPanel>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WPF_StaffReview_v1._0
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Display Windows username
            txtUser.Text = Environment.UserName;

        }


        private void btnLogout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void btnHelp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //ccMain.Content = new UC_About();
            //UC_About.IsVisibleProperty = true;
        }

        private void btnMenuOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnMenuOpen.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            btnMenuCollapse.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void btnMenuCollapse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnMenuOpen.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            btnMenuCollapse.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //var item = ListViewMenu.SelectedItems();
            MessageBox.Show("Selection changed...");

        }

        private void lvMenuHome_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Selection changed`enter code here`...");
    }

    private void lvMenuPReview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selection changed...");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS52U.png)

Comment: Use MVVM and bind the Listview's SelectedItem property.  When that property updates you can trigger additional code as needed.

Comment: Any way I can achieve this without MVVM? (I do appreciate that this is a more effective solution, but I still want to find out what is wrong with the current code.)

Comment: I would say don't stay with outdated code and encourage you to use MVVM which handles many scenarios in an easier and more elegant way.